# ng new with different --source-dir {custom Dir} not working

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am using the angular cli to create a new project. I am following the tutorial from the book [Essential angular for aspnet core mvc.](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484229156)
I get an error that the tsconfig.app.json file cant be found when i try to serve or ng eject after project creation. The command i am using to create the project is this

```
ng new SportsStore --skip-git --skip-commit --skip-tests --source-dir ClientApp
```

if I do

```
ng new SportsStore --skip-git --skip-commit --skip-tests
```

then it creates the project in the src directory fine and it works as expected when i do ng serve or ng eject. I am using the latest version of the angular cli. How do i tell it what source dir to use on creation successfully? Is the only work around to then rename the folder and the path in a bunch of places?

Update: I found that it adds my app in the the source-dir but it still also creats an src folder as well.

Comment: Silly question but are you changing to the "SportsStore" folder (i.e. "cd SportsStore" after the ng new) and then trying to run ng serve?

Comment: Btw, I ran "ng new SportsStore --skip-git --skip-commit --skip-tests --source-dir ClientApp" exactly like you did and I was able to ng serve it.

Comment: I am changing to SportsStore. I cant figure out what is causing the error...this happened to me on a pc and a mac btw.

Comment: what version of angular-cli do you have? Which version of node are you running?

Comment: I recently re -installed the angular cli and i think i have an up to date version of node. I recently installed yarn because bower told me to and i do get a message when creating the project that i can set yarn as my package manager. I am going to try uninstalling yarn.